# Is it possible to compile and use xapian, clucene or lucy on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, lucene, xapian, clucene

I want to compile and use Xapian with xcode on iOS, is there any one with any experiments on this? Is it possible?

Is there any other option for implementing full text search on iOS?I have tried
S4luceneLib (in Obj-C) which works but is port of old version of lucene, also I 
have checked Clucene and lucy, which like xapian i can not compile on iOS.

any help and comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any lick with compiling Xapian on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking as one of the Xapian authors, I don't recall hearing of anyone reporting trying to compile Xapian on iOS.  I also don't know of any fundamental reason why it would be impossible to compile it on iOS.  I suggest you contact the Xapian developer community (on the xapian-discuss mailing list: http://lists.xapian.org/mailman/listinfo/xapian-discuss or on the #xapian IRC channel on irc.freenode.net), and give details of the attempts you've made to compile Xapian, and the error messages or problems you encountered.